# Derivation of inner variations

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, inverse, calculus-of-variations

In Giaquinta's and Hildebrandt's 1996, "Calculus of Variations 1", pages 147-148, they develop the definition of inner variations.

They first fix $\lambda\in C_c^{\infty}(\overline\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $0<\varepsilon_0<(2K)^{-1}$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open bounded set and  $K$ is the Lipschitz constant of $\lambda$.

Then they show that the family of maps:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}=\{\xi_{\varepsilon}: \overline\Omega\rightarrow\overline\Omega\ |\ \varepsilon\in (-\varepsilon_0, \varepsilon_0)\}
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
\xi_{\varepsilon}(y)=y+\varepsilon \lambda(y)\quad y\in \overline\Omega, \ \varepsilon\in(-\varepsilon_0, \varepsilon_0)
\end{equation}
is actually a family of diffeomorphisms of $\overline\Omega$ that further satisfy the conditions:

1. $\xi_0(y)=y$,
2. $\frac{\partial}{\partial\varepsilon}\xi_{0}(y)=\lambda(y)$ and
3. $\xi_{\varepsilon}(y)=y\quad \forall\ x\in\partial\Omega, |\varepsilon|<\varepsilon_0$.

Now, I follow their arguments for demonstrating the above. However, they further say that the inverse mapping of $\xi_{\varepsilon}$ is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\eta_{\varepsilon}(x)=x-\varepsilon\lambda(x)+o(\varepsilon)
\end{equation*}but I don't understand this because if $y\in\text{spt}(\lambda)$ then 
one would expect that $\eta_{\varepsilon}\circ\xi_{\varepsilon}(y)=y$. However,  I get as far as:

\begin{equation*}
\eta_{\varepsilon}\circ\xi_{\varepsilon}(y)=y+\varepsilon\lambda(y)-\varepsilon\lambda[y+\varepsilon\lambda(y)]+o(\varepsilon).
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lambda$ is continuous, we have $\lambda(y+\varepsilon \lambda(y)) = \lambda(y)+o(1)$. Here $o(1)$ (as $\varepsilon\to 0$) is uniform in $y$, since $\lambda$ is a compactly supported perturbation. Hence, 
\begin{equation*}
 y+\varepsilon\lambda(y)-\varepsilon\lambda[y+\varepsilon\lambda(y)]+o(\varepsilon)
=y+\varepsilon\lambda(y)-\varepsilon\lambda(y) + o( \varepsilon) +o(\varepsilon)
=y+o(\varepsilon)
\end{equation*}
as expected.

---

Another way to approach inner variation is to take $\xi$ to be the  flow map associated to vector field $\lambda$. Then $\xi_\varepsilon\circ \xi_{-\varepsilon}$ is obviously the identity map, and $\xi_\varepsilon(y)=y+\varepsilon \lambda(y)+o(\varepsilon)$ follows from the continuity of $\lambda$. This way, positive and negative values of $\varepsilon$ are treated simultaneously.

You may want to consult *Two-dimensional geometric variational problems* by Jost, which also has a derivation of inner variational equations (though in two dimensions only).

Comment: So when they say that $\eta_{\varepsilon}$ is the inverse of $\xi_{\varepsilon}$ they mean up to some $o(\varepsilon)$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$? So instead of \begin{equation} \eta_{\varepsilon}\circ\xi_{\varepsilon}(y)=y\end{equation} we have\begin{equation}\eta_{\varepsilon}\circ\xi_{\varepsilon}(y)=y+o(\varepsilon)?\end{equation}

Comment: @Nirav No, the inverse means the inverse, $\eta_\varepsilon\circ \xi_\varepsilon(y)=y$. But if we use    an asymptotic formula for $\eta_\varepsilon$ with error term $o(\varepsilon)$, we should expect that kind of error term to show up on the right; and it does.